# Interior of polar cone and self-concordant function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $f$ is a [self-concordant](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)(see 9.6.2) barrier of a proper cone $K$ ( solid,convex, closed and pointed) in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It looks like the value of all $\nabla f$ is just the interior of the polar dual $-K^*$.

Examples such as non-negative octant and $-\sum \log(x_i)$ and the positive semi-definite cone $\mathbb{S}_+^n$ and $-\log \det(X)$ seems to suggest it is the case.

I wonder is it true in general or is there any existing material proves this.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely the case, and it is straight out of the seminal text, *Interior Point Polynomial Algorithms in Convex Programming* by Yurii Nesterov and Arkadii Nemirovskii. See Section 2.4.3, "Legendre transformation of a self-concordant logarithmically homogeneous barrier." (Or don't. The book is rather... uh... thick. :-)) I don't think this *exact* observation is cited there, but because of the way the gradient is involved in the Legendre transformation, this property drops out rather simply.